# Trigger touch event in specific physical coordinates in the screen Android

Tags: android

I'm performing a little experiment that requires two activities running side by side to interact. The interaction is very simplistic. Pressing a button in one activity should result in a touch event being triggered anywhere in the other.

I'm not even sure this is possible, it might not be because of security reasons, but I thought I would ask here anyways.

**Is there a way to perform an touch event on position X,Y relative to the physical the screen. (not relative to my current activity)**

Again, I'm doing this just for fun.

Comment: By "side by side" I mean, https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/multi-window.html

Answer (score 0):

I have found this blogpost that explains three possible methods to perform a click on an external activity

http://www.pocketmagic.net/injecting-events-programatically-on-android/

They require root, but for my use this is not an issue. If anyone finds something more simplistic or that doesnt require root, I will mark that answer as correct.